# How do I read the basic authorization in a ASP.Net MVC4 api GET request

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc

I have a phone app that trys to GET data from my web api using RestSharp

```
        private void ButtonTestTap(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var client = new RestClient
        {
            CookieContainer = new CookieContainer(),
            BaseUrl = "http://localhost:21688/api/game",
            Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("muhcow", "123456")
        };

        RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
        request.AddParameter("id", 5);

        //request.AddBody(5);
        client.GetAsync<LoginResult>(request, (response, ds) =>
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Data);
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(response.Content);
        });
    }
```

And then want to read the Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("muhcow", "123456") when my api server recieves this GET request so I can verify the user, but I am not sure how to read the data.

I have this

```
public class GameController : ApiController
    {
        // GET /api/game/5
    public string Get(int id)
    {
        var sdf2 = ControllerContext.Request.Headers.Authorization.Parameter; 

        //return LoginManager.VerifyLogin(loginData);
        return "Some data";
    }
```

But sdf2 just has a wierd value "bXVoY293OjEyMzQ1Ng=="

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That header is base64-encoded. Apply Convert.FromBase64String() to it and you'll see the contents.

Answer (score 1):

Authorization.Parameter is base64 encoded. You can look at an example of how to decode it here http://arcanecode.com/2007/03/21/encoding-strings-to-base64-in-c/

Answer (score 1):

```
System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString (Convert.FromBase64String (this.ControllerContext 

.Request .Headers.Authorization.Parameter ))
```

the result is 
"muhcow", "123456"